# clearInterval doesn't work

Tags: timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I can't figure out how to handle correctly the clearInterval (ou clearTimeout) function.

The context: display several images with a specific pause time. If I let the slider play, the pause times are correct, nothing to say. If I decide to jump to a specific image, the timer is not set to 0 despite a clearInterval, and this image is therefore displayed too shortly (old timer is still active).

What can be wrong with my js code below?

Thanks!

```
function pauseImage () {

var rest=null;

clearInterval(rest); 

rest=setInterval(function() { ...go to the next slide...}, 5000);

};
```

Answer (score 2):

`rest` is scoped to the function. It gets reset each time the function is called. Move it to a wider scope.

```
var rest;
function pauseImage () {
  clearInterval(rest); 
  rest=setInterval(function() { ...go to the next slide...}, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Good observation Quentin, I didn't see that when I did my answer.

Comment: Hi Quentin. Thank you very much, this fix has worked! Cheers. Pascal

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to create and clear an interval:

```
var IntervalObject = self.setInverval("nameOfFunction()", 5000);

//following your example
//var IntervalObject = self.setInverval(function(){ ... },5000)

//to clear it
self.clearInterval(IntervalObject);
```

I hope this helps!

I think you just missed the `self`.

Comment: You should never pass a string to `setInterval`, it breaks scope, is slow, and is hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, I will have it in mind in my future codes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your problem is with the scope of your variable `rest`, make it global as suggested by the other answers.

But beyond that, you would still encounter another problem where you find out the clearInterval() seems not to be working, then the answer below  comes in handy--

So, I have suffered this same problem too many time and usually I just let it be,
But most times I realize that after clearing interval the interval continues to run, and this might affect the performance of the device (it's like having an infinite loop).

So I did a little bit of research and I found out what the problem was and I wrote a simple code to solve it.

Now when you start an interval (most likely triggered by an event) in most cases, more than one instance of that interval is declared (for whatever reason)...

So when you clear the interval later, you only clear the *top-level interval, and the next level interval sets in.
(top-level might not be the correct word)

So to truly clear the interval I used the method below:

**Setting the interval:**

```
if(!timer)   
    timer =setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```

**Clearing the interval:**

```
clearInterval(timer);
timer=null;
while (timer!== null){
    timer=null;
}
```

you might decide to clear the interval inside the while loop, but I found that this works for me and it's quite efficient than that.

> Make sure you check the scope of the interval variable (i.e timer in the case above)